# What does _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL = 1 mean?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, linker

In VS2010, C++ project I get this error when linking in x64/Release:

error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '1'

All other configuration/platform combinations link just fine.  So a static library is built with _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL set to 0 and the .dll that depends on it somehow has _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL set to 1.  I'm trying to figure out what that means so I can figure out how to turn it off!

The only references to this error that I found while Googling are when _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL's conflict with values of 0 and 2.  That indicates an attempt to link release with debug. But I'm sure that's not the case here.

Comment: Linking release with debug library is the only way to get this error. Check it again. If you are sure, check it again, twice.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Well, after struggling with this for an hour I figured it out right after I asked the question... for posterity:

```
_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL = 0 (in release mode)
_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL = 1 (in release mode if _SECURE_SCL is defined)
_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL = 2 (in debug mode)
```

Somehow I had _SECURE_SCL defined as a preprocessor definition only in the Release/x64 configuration of my DLL and I had to squint really hard to notice it.  Once I removed that definition, the error went away.

**Edit:** I found this [nice lecture/tutorial on msdn that (among other things) explains _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/C9-Lectures-Stephan-T-Lavavej-Advanced-STL-3-of-n). Unfortunately, it does require a fairly recent version of Microsoft Silverlight to watch.

Comment: Ran across this today which explains exactly what _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL is for and what its values are if you are curious:   http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/C9-Lectures-Stephan-T-Lavavej-Advanced-STL-3-of-n

Answer (score 3):

For those with immaculate preprocessor definitions, yet still suffering from this error, check the project's runtime library setting.

If set to either one of the debug versions, `_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL` will get set to 2.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this problem on a release build, but I found that my preprocessor was defining _DEBUG when it should have been NDEBUG.  Changing to NDEBUG fixed the problem.