# Debugging cplex project in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, cplex

I cannot compile my c++ project cplex libraries on visual studio.

The versions are cplex 122 and visual studio 2010 on windows 7
the cplex header I use is

```
<ilcplex/ilocplex.h>
```

the cplex libraries linked are

```
C:\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio_AcademicResearch122\cplex\lib\x64_windows_vs2010\stat_mta\cplex122.lib
C:\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio_AcademicResearch122\cplex\lib\x64_windows_vs2010\stat_mta\ilocplex.lib
C:\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio_AcademicResearch122\concert\lib\x64_windows_vs2010\stat_mta\concert.lib
```

All the necessary settings are done for release setting, It compiles and runs without any problems (where I do not encounter my programming bugs)

However, I tried the things on [this](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21439926&wv=1) webpage, and the error I get is many times the following

```
error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in graph.obj    ..\ilocplex.lib(ilocplex.obj)
```

By the way, `graph.obj` is my own object file

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL = 1 mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4130044/what-does-iterator-debug-level-1-mean)

Comment: Please check if the issue you have is same as in the possible duplicate i mentioned. If yes write a comment here so others can vote to close this.

Comment: It only explains that the objects I used from cplex distribution(ilocplex.obj) are release mode, but the ones I compile are in debug mode(graph.obj) as expected. But What I want to find is how do I get cplex object files in debug mode?

Answer (score 0):

You can't link external libraries in VS2010 that are compiled with a different value of _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL. Since you don't have the ability to build a debug version cplex (which would set _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL to 2) you'll need to set _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL to 0 for all of your projects that link with cplex.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa985982.aspx for some background information about _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL

Comment: Yes but my main issue is to debug the cplex project. I looked over IBMs website but could not find any information on debugging projects linked with cplex libraries. Are there any suitable cplex object files suitable for debug mode compilation?

Comment: According to my knowledge there are not cplex libraries built for debug mode compilation.  Changing your iterator debug level in your project doesn't stop you from debugging your project, it just turns off some extra helpful checking in debug mode

Comment: I managed to do a lot of debugging, but VS did not show the values of most local variables are not shown. Mostly, everything I allocate on the heap appear normally, however, I cannot see anything I create in the stack.