# How can i know, What is the ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL value of a .lib file?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-debugging, chromium-embedded

I am generating some .lib(eg- libcef_dll_wrapper.lib) files and later after some steps using this .lib file in myCustomApp. I am getting below error in Visual Studio debug build only.

```
LNK2038 mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in customfile.obj
```

There are many steps between creation of this .lib file and using it in my custom application. Is there any way so that i can check ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL value **just after creation** of this .lib file? Please help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does \_ITERATOR\_DEBUG\_LEVEL = 1 mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4130044/what-does-iterator-debug-level-1-mean) [How to set _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL in VS2010?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5727815/how-to-set-iterator-debug-level-in-vs2010) [_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL error in visual studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4738987/iterator-debug-level-error-in-visual-studio/4739353)

Comment: No, It is different. I just want to know, how can we check ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL value just by using .lib file.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid, how this information is stored in a .lib archive file is not well documented.

A compiler stores the value with the name "_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL" got by `_STRINGIZE(_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL)`.

```
#define _STRINGIZEX(x) #x
#define _STRINGIZE(x) _STRINGIZEX(x)
```

You may parse a .lib archive and .obj files in an archive and look for "_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL" value.

The code bellow from yvals.h detects the value mismatch while linkage, see [#pragma detect_mismatch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/detect-mismatch?view=msvc-170)

```
#pragma detect_mismatch("_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL", _STRINGIZE(_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL))
```

> When you link the project, the linker throws a LNK2038 error if the project contains two objects that have the same name but each has a different value. Use this pragma to prevent inconsistent object files from linking.
>
> Both name and value are string literals and obey the rules for string literals with respect to escape characters and concatenation. They are case-sensitive and cannot contain a comma, equal sign, quotation marks, or the null character.